# No architectures to compile iphone sdk

Tags: ios4, compilation, iphonecoredatarecipes

I'm trying to compile a project from github - `https://github.com/JaredCrawford/iWVU/blob/61448d679192a574a9cc1aa1ee671ffa08e93a6c/Libraries/ARKit/ARViewController.m` . When i run it i get

```
'No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv6, VALID_ARCHS=i386 ppc ppc64 ppc7400 ppc970 x86_64).'
```

and above this in gray its `'Build Three20'`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Also - if i remove the'build tree20' dependancie i get `error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphonesimulator3.0'`.

Answer (score 0):

The error `There is no SDK with the name or path` is usually due to a project referencing a version of the SDK which you don't have.  Check "Base SDK" in Build Settings; you usually want to set it to "Latest iOS".

Are you sure you have the latest version of iWVU?  I just downloaded it and it builds fine for me...